# How to keep previous content of my main component preserved in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-template

In angular 1, I can define any element a root element and that does not replace any inline HTML already written.
eg in angular 1.

```
<body>
  <div ng-app=""> 
    <h1><?php echo $heading_this_page;?></h1>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

But in angular 2, if I write above like this.

```
<body>
  <ng-app> 
    <h1><?php echo $heading_this_page;?></h1>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</ng-app>
</body>
```

and I use `ng-app` as a main/root component selector, the innerHTML of `ng-app` element, gets replaced by the component's HTML.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template:'<h1>App works</h1>";
  directives: [UsersComponent]
})
```

ie the innerHtml of `ng-app` now becomes `<h1>App works</h1>` . I want the previous content of `ng-app` preserved.

And if this is not possible can I do something like below.

```
<body>
      <ng-app> 
        <h1><?php echo $heading_this_page;?></h1>
        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
        <render-component-here></render-component-here>
    </ng-app>
    </body>
```

Where `ng-app` is my main component (bootstrapped on load) and it should render its data in `<render-component-here></render-component-here>` element (and not in itself by replacing previous content)

Comment: Check my updated answer. You will find something interesting that having `ng-content` in the component that you are specifying in index.html won't work

Answer (score 3):

Add `<ng-content></ng-content>` in your component template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template:'<div><h1>App works</h1><ng-content></ng-content></div>';
  directives: [UsersComponent]
})
```

Check [toddmotto](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content) explanation

**Remember that having text in root component(component that is being bootstrapped) will not work with `ng-content`.**

```
<body>
    <ng-app>loading...</ng-app>
</body>
```

NgApp component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template: `
    <h1>App component</h1>
    <my-apps>This is the text by ng-content</my-apps> 
    <ng-content></ng-content>

  `,
})
```

**Having content in all other components will work.**

Check working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDL4Pafh81QrJi2gh4pJ?p=preview)

**loading...** in index.html will always replaced by the `ng-app` component

So, you are in the same case, even you mention the `<ng-content></ng-content>` it won't work. If you want to include that also you must have another parent component and in that you must have `<ng-app>` and now, inside `<ng-app>` you need to have `<ng-content>`

Answer (score 2):

`<ng-content>` is the answer to your query

Change your code

**From :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template:'<h1>App works</h1>";
  directives: [UsersComponent]
})
```

**To :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template:'<h1>App works</h1> <ng-content></ng-content>";
  directives: [UsersComponent]
})
```

If you want to learn more about ng-content :
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content